# Type hint for special keys of dict subclass

Tags: python, dictionary, overloading, type-hinting, python-typing

I would like to create type hints for a specific key of a dictionary. That is to say that the value of a key with a specific name has a specific type.

Say we have a `dict` with value type `Union[int,str]` and now want to specify  that only the key `"intkey"` has a corresponding value of type `int` and all other keys have a value type `str`.

How can we do this? My attempt is below, but that does not work with mypy.

Note: **We cannot use [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) here** because with that all keys must be known in advance.

```py
class SpecialDict(Dict[str,Union[int,str]]):
    @overload                                      # <---- error A
    def __getitem__(self, key: Literal["intkey"],/) -> int: ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, key: str,/) -> str: ...

    def __getitem__(self, key,/): return super().__getitem__(key)

    @overload                                       # <---- error B
    def __setitem__(self, key: Literal["intkey"], val: int,/) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, key: str, val: str, /) -> None: ...

    def __setitem__(self, key, val,/): return super().__setitem__(key, val)
```

But that does not work. mypy 1.4 generates the following errors

- A

  ```
  Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types  [misc]
  ```
- B

  ```
  Signature of "__setitem__" incompatible with supertype "dict"  [override] 
     Superclass:
         def __setitem__(self, str, Union[int, str], /) -> None 
     Subclass:
         @overload
         def __setitem__(self, Literal['intkey'], int, /) -> None
         @overload
         def __setitem__(self, str, str, /) -> None 
  Signature of "__setitem__" incompatible with supertype "MutableMapping"  [override] 
     Superclassmypy(note)
         def __setitem__(self, str, Union[int, str], /) -> None 
     Subclass:
         @overload
         def __setitem__(self, Literal['intkey'], int, /) -> None 
         @overload
         def __setitem__(self, str, str, /) -> None
  ```

I don't know why these errors are there and not even the slightest idea what the problem is of error B.

Comment: It looks like the first error is complaining that there is ambiguity because both the first __getitem__ definitions accept strings. Could you use an Enum for `intkey` or something?

Comment: Well that should work: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html#literal-types.  It seems to be the return value. When I change the str parameter overload return value to Union[int,str] it works.

Comment: The __getitem__ functions you overload have the same input parameter types, so once they are called, I don't think Python will know which one to call. Literal indeed is a specific value, but has the same type as `str`. 
For B, I would suggest that the overload doesn't have the same signature as the overloaded, so it is simply incompatible (but it depends how Python sees the relationship between Union[str,int] and str, I would have though what you wrote was ok too)
I don't see a way to do what you are trying to, but I would greatly be interested if you find a way to :)

Comment: @FiddleStix No, that is not a problem per se. As long as the one that comes _first_ does not shadow the second. In this case `Literal["..."]` is a subtype of `str` and so that is not the issue. The issue is that while the `__getitem__` parameter types are compatible, the **return types** are not.

Comment: @PoneyUHC I think you are misunderstanding the issue here. Python does not care about the types at _runtime_ at all. This is a static typing issue and the errors come from Mypy, not Python. And `Literal["..."]` is a **subtype** of `str`. Regarding the second error, you are almost correct. The problem is that overriding methods and using **narrower types** for the parameters is not type safe (violates the LSP). The relationship is simple: `str` is a subtype of `Union[int, str]`. See my answer below for more details, if you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Error A: Unsafely overlapping overloads

Thankfully, this exact type of error is very well explained in [the Mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#type-checking-the-variants). Allow me to adapt their example to more closely fit your situation, but simplify it a bit and lose the surrounding class:

```py
from typing import Literal, Union, overload


@overload
def f(a: Literal[""]) -> int: ...
@overload
def f(a: str) -> str: ...


def f(a: str) -> Union[int, str]:
    if a == "":
        return 42
    return a.upper()
```

The issue here is that `Literal[""]` is a **subtype** of `str` and your signatures imply that when something of that type (i.e. the literal empty string `""`) is passed to `f`, it will return an integer, but when the **supertype** is passed it will return a string.

Now imagine the following:

```py
s: str
...
s = ""
print(f(s) + " some string")  # TypeError!
```

In other words, `s` can hold **any string** and at runtime at some point it is assigned the **empty string**. Now, once `f` called with `s` as the argument, `f` will see that it is `""` and return an integer, but the type checker can only see that `s` is declared to be `str` and thus assume the return type to be `str` as well. Therefore it has no way of warning you about the coming error attempting to add a string to an integer.

As the documentation puts it, if it were to allow such an overloaded signature, it would

> result in a discrepancy between the inferred type and the actual runtime type when we try using it [...]

Note that this should be considered a **design decision** of the people writing the type checker. They decide how strictly they want to apply their rules for safe/unsafe overloads. Mypy does not apply this rule consistently/to its last logical conclusion and they say this clearly in the documentation. But they also say this: (emphasis mine)

> What this does mean [..] is that you should exercise caution when designing **or using** an overloaded function that can potentially receive values that are an instance of two seemingly unrelated types.

In other words, if you are aware of these dangers, I would say it is perfectly reasonable to apply a `type: ignore[mics]` directive next to your first overloaded signature and move ahead.

---

### Error B: Violating the Liskov Substitution Principle

This is more easily explained, but you have to really familiarize yourself with the [lsp](/questions/tagged/lsp). The implications are also [documented by Mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides).

You are defining a **subtype** of `dict` and overriding one of its methods. The rules of the LSP dictate:

> It’s unsafe to override a method with a **more specific argument type** [or] with a more general return type.

Phrased differently in terms of variance, subtyping is **contravariant** in the method parameter types.

Since you passed `str` as the key type argument and `Union[int, str]` as the value type argument for `dict` during inheritance, this collapses the parameter types in all its methods `str` and `Union[int, str]` for the keys and values respectively. This includes the `__setitem__` method.

But in **none** of your overload signatures, can you call `__setitem__` with those types. You are **strengthening the preconditions** for that method by only allowing either

1. a subtype of `str` (namely `Literal["intkey"]`) for the key and a subtype of `Union[int, str]` (namely `int`) for the value or
2. `str` for the key (which is fine) and **a subtype** of `Union[int, str]` (namely `str`) for the value.

You explicitly do not allow *any* `str` for the key and `str | int` for the value in that method. And strengthening preconditions violates the LSP, ergo is not safe subtyping.

As a practical example, imagine the following:

```py
def func(dictionary: dict[str, Union[int, str]]) -> None:
    dictionary["intkey"] = "spam"


d = SpecialDict()
d["intkey"] = 2

func(d)
print(d["intkey"] ** 2)  # TypeError!
```

This is what what would pass a static type check without a problem, **if** `SpecialDict` were considered a safe subtype of `dict[str, Union[int, str]]`.

There is no real way around this issue in my opinion, if you really want to subclass `dict` like this, without resorting to a deliberate `type: ignore[override]` directive and "hoping it all works out" at runtime.

An alternative would be to subclass the more general [`Mapping` ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes), because that does not have a `__setitem__` method at all and just add that (and any other missing mix-in methods you need like `pop`) yourself. Then there will obviously be no override issue. But that would also mean your `SpecialDict` will not be considered a `dict` or a even a `MutableMapping` subclass by type checkers.

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth explanation. Regarding Error A: Apparently I was incorrectly assuming that the overloads are applied one after another and the first matching is selected. But that is not how it works. Actually what we would need is a (hypothetical) type-hint for a type exclusion, something like "Excluding[str, Literal["intkey"]]" and use that in the second overload. But that does (unfortunately) not seem to exist

Comment: Regarding Error B: Actually I know the Liskov substitution principle. And yes, true, the mutability is the issue. Only for a readonly version of dict this would actually work. I was not thinking this to the end :-) Thanks.

Comment: So, sadly, there seems to be no way to type-hint special, selected keys of a dict.

Comment: @AndreasH. Unfortunately not. Something like the `Excluding` or `Not` that you suggested has been suggested and is being discussed [here](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/801). It is closely related to the missing `Intersection` type, which I have to say comes up even more often for me. But I don't see much progress in that direction right now.

Comment: I agree, having something like Intersection and Not (in addition to the already existing Union), would algebraically close the typing system and thus enable describing arbitrarily complex situations. Hopefully in the future, but not at the moment.